# How to change UIViewControllers like iphone Calculator app does?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

in my app when the phone rotates i want to change the view like the Calculator app does, when it is in portrait it shows the normal calc and when it is in landscape it shows the scientific calc. For example in one of my UIViewControllers, for portrait mode, i will have a grid with images and when it is in landscape i want it to show an image and to be able to swap them like in the Photos app. Could you give me any pointer how can i swap the viewControllers on rotate? 
thank you in advance, Sorin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont swap view controllers, you swap the view, so create a view for each and then when it rotates push the new view in